# C# Core Builder.Attachments, attach Word but the original file with 1 page after attachment became 4 pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailkit

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 and I am trying to attach a Word file into my email. The email is working perfectly, however I had some problems with the attachment.

The original word document has only 1 page, but after being attached and downloaded from the recipient's mail box it started to have 4 pages. Some of text of the 1st page have gone to the 2nd page and in 3rd pages.

Here's my code:

```
public string TestSend()
{
  var webRoot = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
  var pathToFile = "EmailTemplates"
                   + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()
                   + "Test.html";

  var builder = new BodyBuilder();
  using (StreamReader SourceReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(pathToFile))
  {    
    builder.HtmlBody = SourceReader.ReadToEnd();    
  }
  string messageBody = string.Format(builder.HtmlBody,
                       "TEST",
                       "TEST",
                       "TEST",
                       "TEST",
                       "TEST" );    

   builder.HtmlBody = messageBody;
   builder.Attachments.Add(@"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Test\Temp.docx");

   var message = new MimeMessage();
   message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test", Test@test.com));
   message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test", JustDemo@test.com));
   message.Cc.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test", Test@test.com));    

   message.Subject = "Test";
   message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();               

   using (var client = new SmtpClient())
   {
     client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
     client.Authenticate("test@test.com", "Test");
     client.Send(message);
     client.Disconnect(true);    
   }  

     return "a";    
}
```

Comment: There's no `Attachment` type, so what is the code for that?

Comment: @jstedfast Hi, Sorry. What do you mean by theres no Attachment type?

Comment: In your code above, you have: `builder.Attachments.Add (new Attachment (...))`, but that doesn't compile because there's no `Attachment` class.

Comment: @jstedfast Hi I am sorry, I copy paste the wrong code. The new Attachment shouldnt be there. The code runs just fine, only the output which is the word document that came out wrong. Original file is 1 page but then it became 4 pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try forcing the Content-Transfer-Encoding to base64:

```
var attachment = (MimePart) builder.Attachments.Add ("C:\.....");
attachment.ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.But the problem still exist :(

Comment: Oh wait. It is working perfectly fine to be honest. I realise that the error only occured when I viewed the Word in Google Chrome, because the attachment is send to my Gmail. When I view it on Gmail theres few pages, when I download it, theres only one page. Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: Bug in Google Docs?

Comment: Haha could be.Thanks a lot for your help